# How to customize columns in Windows Explorer as default settings?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

I want to add more "date" columns in Windows Explorer, but the settings I changed does not apply as default meaning that if I close the current modified window and re-open any folder in any location in Windows Explorer, the columns I just added are all gone.

Is there a way to setup columns as default?

Comment: Your windows version can play a big part in this, but windows 7, for instance, there are defaults for various folder types (ie, general, videos, music, photos, etc).  To make your current folder's settings be the default for all folders of that type, you'll have to go into Tools -> Folder Options -> View - Apply to Folders. And note you'll have to do that for each "type" of folder if you require the same settings in all folders

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try the below steps to customize the Windows Explorer columns.

1. Open a Windows Explorer window
2. Right-click anywhere that's blank and choose **Customize this folder**
3. Choose **General Items** from the *Optimize this folder for* list box, then click **OK**
4. In Windows Explorer, open the *Tools* menu and click **Folder Options**
5. On the *View* tab click on **Apply to Folders** then click **OK**

This will help you to resolve the issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: not working - windows server 2012 R2

Comment: @Vembutech Is there any way to create a custom view (i.e. add an option to the "Optimize this folder for" menu instead of overwriting an existing one)?

Comment: Is there a way to apply this to the Windows 7 Open/Save dialog?

Comment: Sidenote: You have to do this once **for each** folder type (General, but also Music, etc.) if you want it to be applied to all folders.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to set the Open/Save As defaults in Win 10, including default column widths, which always come up with Name too narrow.

Answer (score 44):

In Windows 10 the option moved.

In Windows Explorer, configure the folder how you like it then:

- Click the **File** menu
- Select **Change folder and search options**

  [image]
- In the **Folder Options** dialog, select the **View** tab
- Click **Apply to Folders**.

  [image]

Comment: For me, this "Apply to Folders" button mentions "all folders of this type". So, these same steps had to be done in a few different places to make sure every type was covered.

Comment: BACKUP your REG key first!! Try this at your own risk!!

Windows key + R, type regedit, press ENTER, navigate to:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local>Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell

Change the string size from BagMRU from 0 to 10000

Hope this solve it!