# Choose column headings order in Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-registry

When creating a new folder in Windows 10 or cleaning the ShellBags, the default columns present in Explorer are `Name`, `Date Modified`, `Type` and `Size` in that order.

I can change the order manually or go to another folder that has the view needed and use this [trick](https://superuser.com/a/861493/939885). I would like to know if there is a registry trick that would create a default behavior whenever a folder is created `Name`, `Size`, `Type`, `Date Modified` and `Date Created` would be the default columns or any other combination, what is/are the key/keys that control the behavior.

I don't know if what is written [here](https://superuser.com/a/1563288/939885) is a solution, but I find it very confusing to decipher and understand.

Comment: There is no permanent fix for Explorer.  The other solution offered in that post was xPlorer2 (Zabkat). That app saves settings in the Registry for repeatability .

Comment: There five Windows Explorer templates that you can modify, e.g. selecting other fields, changing header order. You can set your default template (General Items) as you wish, which applies to new folders (not inside a folder of a different type). https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16694/customize-the-five-windows-folder-templates/  However, if you clear that data in ShellBags, then it's gone.